# Filter choices in form fields based on selected items in fields of the same form django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to create multiple configurations for a game of certain type.

UPDATED:

```
class GameType(models.Model):
    tag = model.CharField()
    name = model.CharField()

class GameConfig(models.Model):
    tag = model.CharField()
    game_type = model.ForeignKey('GameType')
    text_settings = model.ManyToManyField('GameTextSettings')
    levels_settings = model.ManyToManyField('GameLevelSettings')

class GameTextSettings(models.Model):
    tag = model.CharField()
    texts = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=maxLengthText), default=list, blank=True)

class GameLevelSettings(models.Model):
    tag = model.CharField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

It would be very nice if, when creating a new configuration, I can force the user to first input a tag and select a type. When he selects the type I want to give him options to either create new text_settings/level_settings or use text_settings/level_settings associated with another game_configuration for the same type.

I think my DB model is wrong but I have little experience with DBs. I do not want to link the GameLevelSettings or TextSettings directly to GameType since they should be linked only to GameConfiguration, however I do not know how to achieve this 'sorting' when presenting to the user the choices.

What would you suggest?

Thank you

EDIT2: My struggle is with creating the views which will implement my logic. I have no idea how to link views in such a way or how to filter ModelChoiceFields choices based on values extracted from the same form.

Extra info:

scenarios:
So basically I want to allow the user to build up multiple GameConfiguration for a specific GameType. The GameConfigurations has an array of GameLevelSettings and a single TextsSettings. I want to make the each individual GameLevelSettings and TextsSettings reusable so that when the user creates a new GameConfiguration which will have the same levels but different texts he can just reuse the already defined GameLevelSettings.

How I image this should work

1. the user opens the page with the new GameConfiguration create form (duuh :D )
2. On this form the user can select(or create) a GameType and input a tag for the new GameConfiguration
3. Once the user selects a GameType the user is presented with options for the other fields (TextsSettings and array of GameLevelSettings) or has the ability to create a new objects . The values for those fields have been pre-filtered so that only objects, associated with other (previously created) GameConfigurations which are for the same GameType, are displayed.

Concrete scenario:

1. I have 3 GameTypes defined - Blue, Red, Green, and have already created GameConfigurations for all of them with default values.
2. Now I want to create another GameConfiguration for GameType Blue.
3. So I open the create view and input tag "Dark Blue" and select GameType "Blue" from a dropdown.
4. Once I select the GameType all of the values in the other fields get filtered so that they show only objects are associated with the previous Default Blue GameConfiguration and non of the objects which are associated with the Red/Green GameConfigurations are shown - this is basically so that it is easier for the user to not mess up and configure a Blue GameType with a Red TextsSettings

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Could you explain more about the scenarios for the models?  Also, you have no Foreign key on your GameTextSettings model.  Did you know that ArrayField only works for Postgres?

Comment: Yes. I am using Postgres. I will make the scenarios more clear. 1min

Comment: Please take a look. Thank youy

Comment: Please consider that a good question must also be minimal. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. As it is, it's unclear what difficulty you're facing and you've given a lot of general information about the game rather than the problem. For example, if the issue is DB design to support multiple configuration, a lot of the above can be deleted, making it easier for people to read and see if they can help.

Comment: I will edit it in the end with a more concrete question. Thank you

Comment: If you understand your question correctly: You have two form fields: *type* and *configuration*. The user should choose a *type* first, and depending on the choice, to options available in *configuration* will change, so only the relevant options can be selected. Is this what you want? If you want instant client side changes (in the browser), it's not something that can not be done with django alone. You have to utilize client side javascript to respond to user interaction in real time.

Comment: Aaa so it can not be done from the server side... Makes sense :D

Answer (score 4):

[django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) can do this by using FKs and rendering JQuery scripts for fields to filter based on other selections in a form.

From the docs:

*If you have the following model:*

```
class Continent(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Country(models.Model):
        continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Location(models.Model):
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

*And you want that if you select a continent only the countries are available that are located on this continent and the same for areas you can do the following:*

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, 
        chained_field="continent",
        chained_model_field="continent", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

If you'd like to see it in action from a page I made awhile back, check out [Thermaline's BeerCalc](http://brew.thermaline.com/bc/size/single) and select fields from the column at the left.

One thing to know is that you can use form_fields from smart-selects on existing models to filter by FK selection. In this case, I had an existing model ProductType that my Material model has an FK to. In my sizing form, when someone selects a ProductType the Material selections are filtered accordingly.

```
from smart_selects.form_fields import ChainedModelChoiceField

# Arguments = ChainedModelChoiceField(app,model,to_field,modle_field,auto_select=False,show_all=False)

class SizingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    material = ChainedModelChoiceField('tubes', 'Material', 'product_type', 'product_type', False, False)
```